# How should mods be notified of bad migrations?

Tags: discussion, support, migration

[This question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/29269/windows-2008-r2-server-compatible-pci-ide-card) was recently migrated to ServerFault. It's clearly a shopping/product recommendation which is off-topic per the SF faq, and has also generally considered off-topic throughout the network since Jeff wrote [Q&A is Hard, Let's Go Shopping.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) It's also just a really crappy question that shouldn't really warrant migration anyway, even if it were on-topic.

As I've done in the past when other sites migrate things to ServerFault that don't belong, I followed the migration link back to here and flagged it for mod attention with the following explanation: `"This was a poor migration, IMO. It's shopping/product rec which is OT on SF, per the FAQ (and everywhere else on the network, I believe)."`

In this instance, however, my flag was declined with the reason: `"declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention"`.

[image]

I believe that this instance does indeed warrant moderator attention. Especially since it was a mod that made the bad migration in the first place. If you prefer not to be notified by flags, what do you prefer? A full-blown meta question?

Comment: On bad moderator-actioned migrations, I know that I've been encouraged to raise flags on the originating site to provide feedback (and they've always been marked helpful).  I thought this was standard practice for the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: I've flagged loads of poor mod only migrations to help educate people as to what's on topic and acceptable to migrate to SF.

Comment: This question is awaiting acknowledgement from other members of mod team, however, this process appears to be perfectly reasonable IMHO. (Unless otherwise directed, I'd prefer to inquire @Teacher's Lounge w/a "do you want this" and let other SE's mods flag do want/do not want when migrating out)